# SOCKS5 Error 400 Tor

Tags: c, proxy, winsock, tor

I am trying to make a GET request through tor using winsock but it seems to have some sort of an error? When I try it with a normal website it goes through and works. But if I try it with a tor website it simply comes back with error 400. That is because i need to resolve the tor hostname or etc. How would i do this in C?

here is the code

```
     #ifndef MAX_PATHZZ
    #define MAX_PATHZZ 256
   #endif
    #define WINDOWS_USER

   #ifndef INVALID_SOCKET
   #define INVALID_SOCKET (-1)
    #endif



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sock;
int irecv;
char brecv[MAX_PATHZZ];
char header[MAX_PATHZZ * 2];
WSADATA wsa;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) == 0)
{


    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(9050);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

        printf("\nAddress = %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));


        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == 0)
        {
            char buff[] =
            {
                0x05,  
                0x01,  
                0x00   
            };


            send(sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
            printf("Sended (%d) = ", sizeof(buff));
            print_hex(buff, sizeof(buff));


            irecv = recv(sock, brecv, MAX_PATHZZ, 0);
            if (irecv > 0)
            {
                printf("Receved data(%d): ", irecv);
                print_hex(brecv, irecv);



                if (brecv[0] != 0x05) { 
                    printf("Invalid server SOCKS version!\n");
                    goto connection_end;
                }

                if (brecv[1] == 0x02) {
                    printf("Auth is needed!!!\n");
                    goto connection_end;
                }
                if (brecv[1] == 0x00)
                {
                    printf("Connection made :P \n");

                    char buff_step_two[MAX_PATHZZ] =
                    {
                        0x05,    
                        0x01,    
                        0x00,    
                        0x01    
                    };

                    printf("\nSend data step two...\n");
                    struct hostent *st_hostent;
                    struct sockaddr_in addr;
                    struct hostent *host;
                    host = gethostbyname("www.google.com");
                    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
                    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

                    memcpy(buff_step_two + 4, &addr.sin_addr.s_addr, 4);
                    memcpy(buff_step_two + 8, &addr.sin_port, 2);

                    send(sock, buff_step_two, 10, 0);

                    memset(brecv, '\0', MAX_PATHZZ);
                    irecv = recv(sock, brecv, 10, 0);
                    if (irecv > 0)
                    {

                        printf("Receved data(%d): ", irecv);
                        print_hex(brecv, irecv);
                        sprintf(header, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                            "Host: google.com\r\n\r\n");

                        printf("\nHeader...\n%s\n", header);
                        send(sock, header, strlen(header), 0);
                        RtlSecureZeroMemory(brecv, sizeof(brecv));



                            while (recv(sock, brecv, MAX_PATHZZ, 0) > 0){
                                printf("out...\n%s\n", brecv);

                        }

                    }

                    goto connection_end;
                }
            }
        }

    connection_end:

        closesocket(sock);

    }
    WSACleanup();
}
}
```

Comment: Does your Winsock code speak SOCKS?  Sounds like it's connecting to Tor's SOCKS proxy and trying to use it as an HTTP proxy.  Need example code.

Comment: yes it speaks socks @drew010 i added the code

Comment: i simply dont know how to resolve the hostname of a tor domain or how i would go about working with a tor domain

Comment: When working with Tor, you want to let it resolve the domain name (which socks 5 supports).  There was recently a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280186/cant-connect-to-tor-network-via-sock5-c) that has some sample C/C++ code that does a socks request resolving a hostname.  You can probably take a lot of the code from there.

Comment: @drew010 i think the author removed the question :\.... Still need help

Comment: let me guess.... no one knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify a domain in a socks payload, i help you second buffer:

```
char buff_step_two[MAX_PATHZZ] =
                    {
                        0x05,    
                        0x01,    
                        0x00,    
                        0x01    
                    };
```

should be like this:

```
char onion_domain[] = "lol24235235.onion";
short port = 80; // might be 443 also

int onion_len = strlen(onion_domain);

char buff_step_two[MAX_PATHZZ] = { 0x05,0x01,0x00,0x03 };
int n = 4;
buff_step_two[n] = strlen(onion_domain);
memcpy(buff_step_two+n,onion_len,onion_domain);
n += onion_len;

buff_step_two[n] = (port & 0xFF);
n++;
buff_step_two[n] = (port >> 8) & 0xFF;
```

And don use functions like `htons` if you are into tor and that sort of stuff and want to become, hacker try understand how to do simple byte and bit manimulatino by yourself